# Prisma: How do I make the database URL more dynamic in schema file?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I am using Prisma along with Postgres as a DB.

Currently this is how my schema.prisma file looks with DATABASE_URL as below
***DATABASE_URL="postgresql://admin:admin@localhost:5432/nestjs?schema=public"***

**schema.prisma**

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
 
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}
```

I want to know if it possible to make the Postgres URL more dynamic in the schema file.
Is there any way to include more than one environment variable in the schema file?
For example

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = `${${env("DATABASE_DOMAIN")}:${env("DATABASE_USER")}@${env("DATABASE_URL")}/nestjs`
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}
```

Comment: Maybe define `DATABASE_URL` based on other variables you have in your second code?

Comment: There is no mention of using multiple variables in the docs https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/database-reference/connection-urls

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have this working right now is to provide an environment variable that contains full database url. String concatenation is [not implemented](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2559) in Prisma yet.

So you can use an `.env` file to [prepare](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema#accessing-environment-variables-from-the-schema) the environment variable (Prisma v2.7.0+):

```
# .env
DATABASE_URL=${DB_SCHEMA}://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/nestjs
```

Or you can export it as a system variable:

```bash
# Unix
export DATABASE_URL="$DB_SCHEMA://$DB_USER:$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_HOST:$DB_PORT/nestjs"
# Windows
set "DATABASE_URL=%DB_SCHEMA%://%DB_USER%:%DB_PASSWORD%@%DB_HOST%:%DB_PORT%/nestjs"
```